# Xmarin.Forms Android app restarts onResume on Oreo

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, onresume

I have a Xamarin forms Android app that seems to be restarted when the app is brought back to the foreground. (i.e. launch app, tap home button, tap app icon or select app from the recent apps menu.)

This only happens on devices running Oreo and possibly only with the November 2018 patches. I have set the  Activity launch mode to LaunchMode.SingleTask and LaunchMode.SingleTop to no avail.

My users authenticate when they launch the app. This is causing them to have to re-authenticate each and every time they navigate away from the app which is not ideal.

Comment: You self-answered here?[onresume-cause-app-to-restart-on-oreo](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/148681/onresume-cause-app-to-restart-on-oreo)

Comment: I posted this same question to a number of forums. I found the answer on another forum. My issue was that I had "Do not keep activities" turned on under developer options on the device. Apparently this setting terminates activities when the app looses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this issue on another forum. I had "Do not keep activities" enabled on the device I was using to test. The setting is located under developer options. I had no idea that setting existed.